# find maximum values per column inside nested list except the first one

Tags: python-3.x

I have to find maximum elements per column except the first column inside the nested list I tried using that but that didn't worked

`v=[['a',1,10,3],['b',2,3,11],['c',3,4,5]]`

```
answer =v[0]
```

```
for current in v[1:]:
    answer = [max(x, y) for x, y in zip(answer[0][1:], current[1:])]
print(answer)
```

it should return `[3,10,11]`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
ans = [max(i) for i in list(zip(*v))[1:]]
```